# How to use multithreading/concurrency in my Java code

Tags: java, multithreading

This is a simplification of my code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    someMethod(i);
}
```

`someMethod()` takes a long time to execute, so I want to use multithreading to break up the for-loop into 5 intervals of 100:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    someMethod(i);
}

for(int i = 100; i < 200; i++) {
    someMethod(i);
}

...

for(int i = 400; i < 500; i++) {
    someMethod(i);
}
```

so I can execute `someMethod()` concurrently for different `i`.

How do I use multithreading to accomplish this?

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Use ExecutorServices and threadpool

Comment: Small and really basic sample [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/basicthread.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is recommended to use the great `ExecutorService` code for situations like this.  What you do is submit all of your tasks (0 to 499) into the thread pool and they will be run concurrently by the 5 threads in the pool.

Something like the following:

```
// create a thread pool with 5 workers
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
// submit all of your jobs here
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    threadPool.submit(new MyJob(i));
}
// once we have submitted all jobs to the thread pool, it should be shutdown
threadPool.shutdown();
// if you need to wait for the pool you can do
threadPool.awaitTerminatation(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

```
private static class MyJob implements Runnable {
   private int i;
   public MyJob(int i) {
       this.i = i;
   }
   public void run() {
       // do the thread stuff here
   }
}
```

Comment: By `// do the thread stuff here`, what do you mean? Also, where does `someMethod()` factor into this?

Comment: So @Jessica, you can copy what is in `someMethod()` and put that code into `run()`.  You could also pass in the class that forks the thread into the `MyJob` constructor and then inside of run do:  `caller.someMethod(i)`.  Your choice.

Comment: just replace `// do the thread stuff here` with `someMethod(i);` :) .. +1 for Gray

Comment: One more question, if anyone is still around: I have a `boolean done = false` at the beginning of my code. One of those `i` values will toggle `done`. I want to stop the for-loop when that happens. Right now I added `if(done) return;` to `run()` but all the `someMethod()`s that have already started need to `return;` so there's a short time delay. What's a better way to do this?

Comment: That's harder because the jobs have already been submitted to the thread-pool.  You could make `done` be volatile and just put a `if (done) return;` the first thing in the `run()` method @Jessica.

Comment: @JessicaMyers maybe you could interrupt all other thread using Thread.interrupt(). For more explanation, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680525/how-do-i-kill-a-thread-from-another-thread-in-java